# PHP magic functions __get, __set execution orders

Tags: php

For the following code, I expected

> A,b,B,c,C,c:CC,A,b,B,c,C

as output. But I am getting

> b,c,A,B,C,c: CCb,c,A,B,C

Can somebody explain me please, how it works ?

Here is my code

```
class Magic
{
    public $a = "A";
    protected $b = array("a"=>"A","b"=>"B","c"=>"C");
    protected $c = array(1,2,3);

    public function __get($name)
    {
        echo "$name,";
        return $this->b[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "$name: $value";
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

}

$m = new Magic();
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";
$m->c = "CC";
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c;
```

Comment: `__get` or `__set` is only used on properties that dont exist, `public $a` exists...  by exists I mean accessible.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `__get` method isn't used for `$m->a`. The magic method is only used for getting inaccessible properties. Since `a` is a public property, it's retrieved the normal way.

The reason the output of the `__get` methods doesn't alternate with the values is because the entire value of the `echo` argument is calculated before it prints anything. So

```
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";
```

is equivalent to

```
$temp = $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";
echo $temp;
```

So first it gets the values of all 3 properties, which calls the magic methods for `$m->b` and `$m->c`, and these print the property names and return the values from the `$b` array. Then it concatenates all the returned values, and finally it prints this concatenated result.